# Given N cards with a number on both sides of it, find the minimum Z = C1 - C2 + C3 - ... + Cn

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Problem: Given N cards, each side of a card has an integer. I calls Z = {card 1} - {card 2} + {card 3} - ... + {card n}. Calculate the minimum value of the face-up card. Note that you can move and flip any of them.

For example N = 6, cards = [[-8, 12], [0, 5], [7, -3], [1, 4], [10, -7], [-2, 7]]. The minimum Z of this case is -34, which is (-8) - 5 + (-3) - 7 + (-7) - 4.

I'd think of sorting these cards in non-increasing order by the sum of each card, then flip the card to make the smallest Z possible. But it seems to be wrong.

In the above example, I sorted the cards by their sum is [[0,5][-2,7],[1,4],[-8,12],[7,-3],[10,-7]] and then calculate Z = 0 - 7 + 1 - 12 - 3 - 10 = -31, which is a wrong answer.

```
def get_min_Z(cards):
    cards = sorted(cards, key=lambda c: c[0] + c[1], reverse=True)
    z = 0
    current = 1;
    for card in range(len(cards)):
        z = z + min(current*cards[card][0], current*cards[card][1])
        current = -current
    return z

cards = [[-8, 12], [0, 5], [7, -3], [10, -7], [-2, 7], [1, 4]]
min_z = get_min_Z(cards)
print(min_z)
```

I also think of using dynamic programming, but I have no idea how to use that on this problem.

I have searched this problem in the internet, but i can't find any similar problem like this.

Please help me to solve this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each card will have a score if it is a + term, and a different score if it is a - term.  For your example:

```
   CARD      +value   -value    diff
[-8, 12]         -8      -12       4
[ 0,  5]          0       -5       5
[ 7, -3]         -3       -7       4
[ 1,  4]          1       -4       5
[10, -7]         -7      -10       3
[-2,  7]         -2       -7       5
```

Now sort them by `diff`

```
   CARD      +value   -value    diff
[10, -7]         -7      -10       3
[-8, 12]         -8      -12       4
[ 7, -3]         -3       -7       4
[ 1,  4]          1       -4       5
[-2,  7]         -2       -7       5
[ 0,  5]          0       -5       5
```

Now we deal them top, bottom, top, bottom, etc.

```
   CARD      +value   -value    diff    sign   value
[10, -7]         -7      -10       3       +      -7
[ 0,  5]          0       -5       5       -      -5
[-8, 12]         -8      -12       4       +      -8
[-2,  7]         -2       -7       5       -      -7
[ 7, -3]         -3       -7       4       +      -3
[ 1,  4]          1       -4       5       -      -4
                                                ----
                                                 -34
```

Now attempt to convince yourself that this is always optimal, and figure out how to code it.